# Get JSON data out of the Scope

Tags: jquery, json, function, callback

I have this data inside a JSON:

```json
{"minmax":["0.01","67.00"]}
```

And I want to get it using jQuery, this is what I am doing:

```js
$.getJSON("../../dados/opcoesMinMax.json", function(data) {
    var getMinMax = data;
});

// Need to use data here, out of the scope
```

I also tried to do it using callback, doing this:

```js
function getMinMax(callback) {
    $.getJSON("../../dados/opcoesMinMax.json", function(data) {
        callback(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
}

// Need to use data here, out of the scope
```

Even using callback, I cannot recover data. `console.log(getMinMax);` returns me the function.
and `console.log(getMinMax());` returns me undefined and says **callback is not a function**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second pattern you use is valid, and will work. The issue is because in your call to `getMinMax()` you need to provide the callback function as an argument. This is why you're currently seeing the 'callback is not a function' error. Try this:

```js
function getMinMax(callback) {
  $.getJSON("../../dados/opcoesMinMax.json", callback);
}

getMinMax(data => {
  // this is the callback function. Work with the data here...
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Works pretty fine. Appreciate!